# Authentication on ASI HTTP Request in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, asihttprequest, basic-authentication

I've been having this problem for a while when its came to loggin in and posting a review via ASI HTTP request libraries on my iphone app. Its either my login is not saving successfully, I am not sending the username and password to the server to login before I post the review or the review POST method is wrong... If anyone could help I would really appreciate it as I've been banging my head off the wall for a few months.

Login method

```
- (IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *wsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com/login_check.xml"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:wsURL];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;
    [request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:self.username.text andPassword:self.password.text];
    //[request setUsername:self.username.text];
   // [request setPassword:self.password.text];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    self.Login = YES;
    self.SubmitBool = NO;

}
```

Review post method

```
-(void)Submit
{
    NSURL *url = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://furious-ice-356.heroku.com/places/%@/reviews.xml",self.identifier]]];


    self.bestnight.text = @"Monday";

    ASIFormDataRequest *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [request1 setUsername:self.username];
    [request1 setPassword:self.password];

    //[request1 setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    //[request1 setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:NO];

    [request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


    [request1 setPostValue:self.bestnight.text forKey:@"review[best-night]"];
    [request1 setPostValue:self.comments.text forKey:@"review[comments]"];
    [request1 setPostValue:self.StarRating.text forKey:@"review[rating]"];

    [request1 setDelegate:self];
    [request1 startAsynchronous];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

}
```

I am able to add reviews etc on the web service however I can't seem to do it via asi requests.

Thanks in advance